# How to lock a database to a liquibase context?

Tags: liquibase

we've basically two liquibase contexts: *seed* with DDL and reference data, and *qa* with a shared set of test data.

This allows us to create and update either production-like DB instance (context = seed) or qa DB instance (context = seed, qa).

We sometime need to copy (a subset of) the production DB in a qa environment.

At that point, it would be possible for someone to attempt to update such a copy, which had only seen a context = seed, with a context of seed and qa. This will most certainly fail eventually, but I'm looking for a way to make that impossible and fail fast with a nice, comprehensible error message.

Does liquibase support this?

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: liquibase is primarily used for the creation of the DB structure. If I understand your question correctly you also want to load data. And give an error message when someone wants to update the data (of the subset-copy)?

Comment: Yes, we're using liquibase to load a minimal set of test data and credentials<http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html#using-contexts-for-test-data>. We do that to have controlled build & smoke-test environments.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Liquibase to directly support this. The easiest approach would probably be to use preconditions that run under certain contexts and check for something in the database state and fail if it doesn't match what you would expect for that context.

For your example, probably a sqlCheck querying for the existence of certain QA data.